# How to receive ip multicast, using only one NIC

Tags: windows, network-programming, winsock, multicast

I have server with multiple NICs, running windows server 2003. My application receive multicast packets, but now i need to receive multicast packets just from one single network interface. I think this can help, but i have some questions.

```
ip_mreq   mreq;

mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = multicast group address
mreq.imr_interface.s_addr=  network interface address
if (setsockopt( socet
              , IPPROTO_IP
              , IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP
              , (const void *)&mreq
              , sizeof(mreq)) < 0)
{
   std::cerr << "setsockopt error" << std::endl;
}
```

First of all, what do i need to use as a network interface address? Local address of the network interface(same that ipconfig returns), or index of the network interface, that i can get using GetAdaptersAddresses api function?

Second, is this actualy possible with windows, or i just spend my time?

**Update**
I just read about WSAJoinLeaf function, and i wonder, that it is not possible to use only one NIC for multicasts.

Comment: re: "use local address? or index? -- that depends on whether you are talking IPv4 or IPv6 and which API you are using.  In Windows, C#, System.Net there are several signatures for JoinMulticastGroup. Some work better for IPv4, other for IPv6.  You need to read the details of ALL versions of this method to decide which should work best in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: your choice. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738695(VS.85).aspx

Second: Yes, this should definitely be possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works, you can use [GetAdaptersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917(VS.85).aspx) for IPv4 only interfaces, or [GetAdaptersAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915(VS.85).aspx) for both families.

Note that mreq only specifies an interface by address not index, the ip6_mreq and [GROUP_REQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb427440(VS.85).aspx) (family agnostic) versions prefer an index because IPv6 allows you to have multiple matching link-local addresses but be connected to different networks.